# How to send login status with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to send login status with AJAX, here is my code:

```
<img style="display:none;" src="https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=%2Fimages%2Fspinner.gif" onload="show_login_status('Twitter', true)" onerror="show_login_status('Twitter', false)" />

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function show_login_status(network, status)
   {
    if (status)
    {
    alert("Logged in to " + network);
    }else{
     alert("Not logged in to " + network);
    }
   }
</script>
```

How can I create a string from this code, which will AJAX use to send...

```
$.ajax
        ({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'save.php',
          cache: false,
          data: {
    social : <SOME STRING>,
  },
    });
```

Comment: Send what exactly, it's not very clear what you're trying to do ?

Comment: I need to send result of loggin status (You are logged in to Twitter or You are not logged in to Twitter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global variable

```
<img style="display:none;" src="https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=%2Fimages%2Fspinner.gif" onload="show_login_status('Twitter', true)" onerror="show_login_status('Twitter', false)" />
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_login_status(network, status) {
        if (status) {
            logStatus = "Logged in to " + network;
        } else {
            logStatus = "Not logged in to " + network;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'save.php',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                social: logStatus
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It says: Uncaught ReferenceError: logStatus is not defined

Comment: @طالبالتوحيد, OK why don't you make the ajax request inside of `show_login_status()` function? I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exacly sure what your doing but: You could store this as varable like so.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var msg = "";
   function show_login_status(network, status)
   {
    if (status)
    {
       msg = "Logged in to " + network;
    }else{
       msg = "Not logged in to " + network;
    }
    alert(msg);
   }
</script>
```

and later in you ajax call it like so:

```
$.ajax
        ({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'save.php',
          cache: false,
          data: {
    social : msg,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the ajax response using [the .done() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax ({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'save.php',
      cache: false,
      data: {
          social : <SOME STRING>,
      },
    }).done(function(response){
        //examine the response and update your status here
        show_login_status(network, status)
    });
```

You'll definitely want to [read the documentation on this one](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it's full of useful information.